# Upload file to HttpConnection - BLACKBERRY/ JavaME

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I like to upload a file to a http server. This is the code I have so far. The problem is the file is not being uploaded at all. What wrong with the code?

update: I have managed to solve it. Anyone having same problem, maybe this code might help.

```
try{ 
   FileConnection path = (FileConnection)Connector.open(main_directory + "status.zip");
                if (!path.exists()) {path.create();}  

                 byte[] buf ; 
                 buf = new byte[(int) path.fileSize()];

                in = path.openInputStream();
                in.read(buf);

                Logger.logEventInfo("FILE INPUT: " + in);
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(buf.length);                    
                Base64OutputStream base64 = new Base64OutputStream( outputstream );           
                    base64.write(buf);
```

String upload= null;
                    upload= outputstream.toString();

Comment: It is looping at  while ((length = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                                     bout.write(buf, 0, length);
                                  }

Comment: Your code is confusing. There are potentially a lot of things which can be eliminated/simplified. But at least the line `String FileUpload = new String(byout.toByteArray(), "UTF8");` doesn't look very good.

Comment: I am trying to open the file and write into a String so that I can upload into server.

Comment: How shall I change the line String FileUpload = new String(byout.toByteArray(), "UTF8");?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem BalusC has with that line, but it looks OK to me. What is the current status of your problem? Did the change in the while statement solve the looping problem? If so you will need to complete the code because what you have posted isn't finished.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling InputStream.read( byte[] ) with a zero-length byte array, which by definition always returns 0 (no bytes read), which is why your while loop never exits.

Well, that's your first problem. There are many other issues with this code.